# info.plist is still missing after creation of IPA

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been exported an unity project as XCODE project. now its running well on local iPad. Now I need to upload it on testflightapp.com. I have successfully created an IPA. While uploading on testflightapp.com. I am always getting "This IPA does not have valid info.plist file."

I got validation option while exporting. I tried to validate their before uploading. I am getting same error message "This IPA does not have valid info.plist file.", but info.plist is already there.

Comment: testflight look for the info.plist in the correct path. If you uploaded a zipped version of your source code to TestFlight you'll likely get this error. [Help Testflight](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402741-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-3-)

Comment: I have added one <porjectname Tests->info.plist under supporting files dir. one more info.plist is directly under project. and i am creating my IPA through Product->Archive.

Comment: My project is missing Entitlement.plist file. It might be a cause for that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try opening the IPA? unzip that file and you should see the info.plist there. verify if something is not what you are expecting. Confirm if info.plist is as expected. We will look at other options

Comment: No i did not open it yet. Thanks for help :)

Comment: i opened it. it has only one file named as <ProuductName> of application type. there is no file else like info.plist. :(

Comment: @RaviAnand for opening .app file , right click on app->select contents. you should see plist file.

Comment: There is also a target membership window. there are two dir for info.plist. no one is checked?